# Header file compiles multiple times and gets random errors at every compile after the first compile

Tags: c++, compilation, header

When I go to build my C++ project, I get 53 errors. However, it's the same list of errors 4 times in a row from one of the 5 header files I have in my project. I checked the output and found that it attempted to compile that one header file 5 times. It appears that the first time was successful. The other 4 times got errors, but they were the same errors over and over again. I followed where the includes of lead to. Based on all of the places that I include that header file, it makes sense that it would try to compile it for every time that it's included.

This is the header file that's getting compiled multiple times. The first successful compile makes sense, but I don't understand why it's getting a bunch of errors every other time it compiles while building the project:

```
#ifndef TRANSACTION_H
#define TRANSACTION_H

#include <string>
#include "Account.h"
#include "BSTree.h"

using namespace std;

class Transaction
{
public:
    Transaction();
    Transaction(char type, string firstName, string lastName, int ID, Account* account1, int fund1, Account* account2, int fund2, int amount);
    ~Transaction();
    void setPtrAccounts(BSTree* ptrAccounts);
    bool Transact();
private:
    static BSTree* ptrAccounts;
    char type;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    int ID;
    Account* account1;
    int fund1;
    Account* account2;
    int fund2;
    int amount;
    void Deposit();
    void History();
    void Open();
    bool Transfer();
    bool Withdraw();
};

#endif
```

Here's the repeating list of errors. These errors are completely bogus. There's nothing wrong with the code in the above header file:

error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Account'    \thejollybanker\transaction.h   14  1

error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'BSTree' \thejollybanker\transaction.h   16  1

error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'  \thejollybanker\transaction.h   19  1

error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. \thejollybanker\transaction.h    19  1

error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'  \thejollybanker\transaction.h   24  1

error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   \thejollybanker\transaction.h   24  1

error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'  \thejollybanker\transaction.h   26  1

error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   \thejollybanker\transaction.h   26  1

> Here's a summary of the output window:
>
> Transaction.cpp
>
> TheJollyBanker.cpp
>
> **Transaction.h errors**
>
> Fund.cpp
>
> BSTree.cpp
>
> **Transaction.h errors**
>
> Bank.h
>
> **Transaction.h errors**
>
> Account.cpp
>
> **Transaction.h errors**
>
> Generating Code...

How do I get it to only compile it once so that it successfully compiles the first time?

Comment: Hard to say why it fails without more context. However, this header will not compile on its own. It depends on `namespace std` being used, for example. So, if you include this file after a `using namespace std` statement, it could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string` is part of namespace `std`. Replace `string` with `std::string` everywhere in that header, then it should work.

Comment: Good call so far. I can't believe I missed that. I'm now down to 37 errors because it's not complaining about the strings that I use in Transaction.h. However, the errors stemming from the use of my own defined classes Account.h and BSTree.h that you see here in the error list are still present.

Comment: Circular header dependencies? If `transaction.h` is included in `Account.h` or `BSTree.h`, the class definition of `Transaction` can appear before both `Account` and `BSTree`. In that case, forward-declare `Account` and `BSTree` directly before `class Transaction` (`class Account; class BSTree;`). If that isn't it, I can't see the error from the code you posted.

Comment: "Circular dependency". That's it! Upon searching for other Stack Overflow questions, I came across the answer. Essentially, each include needs a respective class declaration and every use of the included classes must be references or pointers. I did this for each of the five classes, and now it compiles. Case close. Thank you. (I don't know if there's anything else I can do to increase your reputation, but I've already accepted your answer).